# having a hard time with columns in python

Tags: python

I am having such a hard time understanding how to make a column-base data table in python and inside a Jupyter notebook. I have attached what my output looks like and the instructions on how to implement them. I'm so close yet so far. Here is my code:

```
def head(column_table: dict[str, list[str]], rows: int) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
    """Produce a column-based table with only the first N rows of data for each column."""
    result: dict[str, list[str]] = {}
    for column in column_table:
        new_list: list[str] = []
        for column in column_table:
            new_list.append(column)
    result[column] = new_list
    return result
```

Please help! What am I doing wrong?

[image: Instructions on what I need to do.]

[image: What my output looks like.]

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm supposed to only see the first five columns of the data given from an excel spreadsheet and this is only displaying the names of the given rows and not the actual data values.

Comment: You do NOT need two nested loops here (both using the same variable), and you are not using the `rows` parameter at all.  You don't want to copy the entire list each time; that's the whole point of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually like to give answers to homework question, but I don't think you're on the right track here.

```
def head(column_table: dict[str, list[str]], rows: int) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
    """Produce a column-based table with only the first N rows of data for each column."""
    result: dict[str, list[str]] = {}
    for key,data in column_table.items():
        result[key] = data[:rows]
    return result
```

Or, if you insist on using a loop:

```
def head(column_table: dict[str, list[str]], rows: int) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
    """Produce a column-based table with only the first N rows of data for each column."""
    result: dict[str, list[str]] = {}
    for key,data in column_table.items():
        newrow = []
        for i in range(rows):
            newrow[i] = data[i]
        result[key] = newrow
    return result
```